# Problema na conversão de JSON em dataframe no R

Tags: json, r, web-scraping

Quero extrair um conteúdo no formato JSON de um site e converter em um dataframe

Site é `https://schutz-shoes.com/products/amaia-sandal-metallic-leather?color=ouro%20gold`

Dentro desse site, apertando `F12`, e indo em `Network`, consigo um link para o API que traz os preço do produto, dado no link a seguir

```
https://schutz-shoes.com/tools/verge-json-ld?url=https://schutz-shoes.com/products/amaia-sandal-metallic-leather?color=ouro%20gold
```

É desse API que quero extrair conteúdo `JSON` para um `data.frame`

Tentei o seguinte método

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

a<-GET("https://schutz-shoes.com/tools/verge-json-ld?url=https://schutz-shoes.com/products/amaia-sandal-metallic-leather?color=ouro%20gold")
a<-content(a,"text")
b<-fromJSON(a)
```

Porém recebo o seguinte erro

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid character inside string.
          ail and walk-able chunky heel.  Material: Metallic Leather H
                     (right here) ------^
```

Gostaria de contornar o erro, mas não sei a fonte do problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, vou deixar aqui a solução

Faltava o encoding, pois o site não é brasileiro

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

a<-GET("https://schutz-shoes.com/tools/verge-json-ld?url=https://schutz-shoes.com/products/amaia-sandal-metallic-leather?color=ouro%20gold")
a<-content(a,type = "text",encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
b<-fromJSON(a)
```

Comment: Bom saber que o problema tem solução.